# Catch event when re-import the same video by using tag input tyle=file

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Could you please show me solution about how to catch event when click button brown to re-import the same video in tag input with type is file?

in video.html:
`<input type="file" (change)="applyVideo($event)>`

in video.ts:

```
applyVideo(event) {
   this.video = event.tartget.files;
}
```

But the function applyVideo do not run even debuging.